# edit fields in twitter bootstrap modal code Igniter

Tags: php, json, codeigniter, jquery, twitter-bootstrap

i am working in a code igniter ... i have records showing in my view page in a table .. in every row there is an edit button .. what i want is if i click on the edit button, modal pop up with the old values .. and then update the fields..i dont know how can i 
first pass the parameter to the controller and then get the values from controller and display in the modal without reloading the page ..well this is what i am doing ..

my view page ..this is my form in my MODAL

```
  <div class="modal hide fade in" id="myModal">
<div class="modal-header">
  <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal">×</button>
<h3>Check information</h3>
    </div>
    <div class="modal-body">

Employee name:<?php echo form_input($emp_name); ?>
</div>
```

the table which is showing the records

```
  <td><?php echo $row->emp_name ?></td>
  <td><a  href="employesController/<?php echo $row->emp_id ?>"class = "edit">Edit       </a> </td>
```

my javascript

```
      <script type='text/javascript'>
$(document).ready(function(){
    $(".edit").click(function(){
        $('.modal').modal('show');


       });
});
</script>
```

my controller

```
  function editEmploye(){

 $id = $this->uri->segment(3);
$this->load->model('employesModel');
$data['result'] = $this->employesModel->getEditEmploye($id);

}
```

how can i send parameter to the controller and launch modal with the old values ?

Answer (score 0):

Bootstrap Modal loads the form that exists in the modal when the page loads. When the modal appears, the page is not refreshing, but the modal javascript is merely showing the form that was loaded(but hidden) from before.

To answer your question on how to prefill the form, I am assuming you are in the following scenario.

You have a table. Eg.

```
Food        |    Price
Fries       |    $1.00
Burger      |    $3.00
```

And assuming you click on Fries, you want your Modal form to be prefilled with

```
<input name="food" value="fries" />
<input name="price" value="$1.00" />
```

I hope I got you right thus far.

You have a form which has

```
<input id="food_name" name="food" value="" />
<input id="food_price" name="price" value="" />
```

to begin with.

First, you add a class to the  of each row on your table. (Or div, if you're using a div as a wrapper.)

```
<table>
  <tr class="food_list">
    <td>Fries</td><td>$1.00</td>
  </tr>
<table>
```

You then use javascript/jquery to detect the **VALUE** of the child of the  tag, which would be the value of the  tag corresponding to it. Please refer to [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7134492/jquery-get-nested-a-element-attribute-inside-div-element). Set a jquery onclick for this.

You can then set do a $('#food_name').val('valueGottenFromAbove') to pre-fill the form.

I'm unable to provide you with a working example, but this is, I believe, a working algorithm to pre-fill that bootstrap modal form.

Good luck.

Please use classes and ids as you see fit. I'm just providing an algorithm that will hopefully help you understand how to approach this.